# usar charAt sin usar charAt

Tags: java, char

Hola estoy haciendo una tarea pero el caso es que, no puedo usar charAt, tengo por así decirlo crear el método desde cero, pero a la hora de pedir al usuario la posición a imprimir no se como comparar la posición con el arreglo

```
Scanner leer = new Scanner(System.in);
Inicio ref = new Inicio();

public void caracter(){
    System.out.println("Ingrese una palabra");
    ref.pal = leer.nextLine();
    char[] arr1 = ref.pal.toCharArray();
    System.out.println("Ingrese la posicion del arreglo que desea ver: ");
    ref.pos = leer.nextInt();
}
```

Comment: lo que quiero en si es pedir al usuario la posición, comparar con el arreglo y imprimir la posición que pide

Comment: ¿No puedes usar simplemente `arr1[i]` siendo `i` la posición que se desea ver? ¿Cuál es la complicación?

Comment: es que a la hora de hacer la comparación me marca error de compatibilidad de datos, investigue y podría ser con el método equals pero no estoy seguro

Comment: Yo veo funciona perfectamente https://onlinegdb.com/ntIxaMYzl

Comment: @JaimeMenéndez si gracias ya vi mi error, utilice mal los datos, gracias:D

Answer (score 1):

Yahir.

Te propongo otra posible solución además de la que ya te han propuesto. Esta vez usando el método substring. Te adjunto código.

```java
    public static Character myCharAt(String text, int x){
        return (Character) text.substring(x, x+1).toCharArray()[0];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes crear un método, no sé qué sea la clase `Inicio` pero puedes implementar un método que convierta el String a un arreglo y luego retorne la posición indicada.

```java
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(myCharAt("Hola mundo", 5));
    }

    public static char myCharAt(String text, int position) {
        return text.toCharArray()[position];
    }
}
```